# Formatting template in Smarty

Tags: php, html, smarty

Template after processing in Smarty loses formatting

Before (source in n++):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
    <head>
```

After (source in browser):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='ru'><head>
```

And i dont know how to fix it. Help!

Comment: Are you using HTML5 for sure? Because the `!DOCTYPE` that you have provided here is the DTD for HTML5 in case you're using any other version of HTML try putting in the appropriate HTML DTD because a wrong DTD would render your template in an unusual manner.

Comment: And kindly elaborate on your question. It needs details if it needs answers.

Comment: You do not understand. After processing template in Smarty, totally lost code formatting (padding, tabs, etc.). Sorry for my English :>

Answer (score 2):

As @GordonM explained, "source formatting" is not necessary when dealing with browsers. It may help humans, but that's about it.

a) Using (Firefox|Chrome|Safari)'s Developer Console, will give you an interactive, nicely structured view of the DOM. Disregarding any whitespace that may or may not be present. These are the tools we want to be using.

b) Smarty comes with an outputfilter called trimwhitespace. If you apply that filter, all unnecessary whitespace and comments are removed. This is done to reduce the size of text that has to be transfered to the browser. You want to send as little as possible for a better performance. We are calling this "minification". You may have heard of it in the Javascript and CSS world.

c) Your example code displays with line breaks and spaces, after I run it through Smarty 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Formatting is unimportant to HTML parsers.  The browser will display the same output regardless of whether it contains white space or not.

But is it really matters, then you do have a few options.

The first is to install the Tidy extension for PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php).  You can then capture the output of Smarty to a string and pass that through the tidy functions to get a formatted HTML string.

The second is to use an external command line utility such as htmltidy.  You can capture your output to a string and pass it to the command line utility with exec().

But honestly, I don't think the effort involved is really worth it as like I said, HTML parsers are unconcerned with white space.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Smarty is set to remove all whitespaces from HTML output (assuming you are using Smarty 3, check if you are using an output filter that do that, info ***[here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.outputfilters.tpl)***) and check also if your template content is wrapped into ***`{strip}`*** tags (info ***[here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.strip.tpl)***).

If you are not using one of these filters/tags, I'm afraid the problem is not Smarty, but a minification process somewhere else....